# Friend declaration not working with typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, friend, c++03

When I write a friend declaration like this

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {};

struct Bar { 
    friend class Foo<Bar>;
};
```

everything is fine. However, when I use a typedef

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {};

struct Bar {
    typedef Foo<Bar> FooBar; 
    friend class FooBar;
};
```

gcc (4.4.7) complains with

```
error: using typedef-name ‘Bar::FooBar’ after ‘class’ 
error: ‘Bar::FooBar’ has a previous declaration here 
error: friend declaration does not name a class or function
```

I always thought a `typedef` behaves exactly the same as if I typed the original type.... Is it not allowed to use a `typedef` here? or am I just using it wrong?

PS: the template turned out to be a red herring, the following will cause the same error

```
struct Foo{};
struct Bar{
    typedef Foo FooBar;
    friend class FooBar;
};
```

Comment: You need to remove `class` or `struct` keyword with friend declaration

Comment: @P0W nope, then I get an error saying that `a class-key must be used when declaring a friend`

Comment: @Hm, idk. I thought it was working in 4.7.

Comment: @P0W works on 4.8.5 (with and without `-std=c++11`)